# Find Link in div with javascript and go to it

Tags: javascript, html

Actually i find a Element (div1) i want to find a Link in the element like (link) and want go to it

```
<div class="div1">
<p>
    <a href="link">Link</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not show a lot of research before posting :/

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your html (add id to Anchor property) you can use getElementById method in JavaScript.

```
var link = document.getElementById("myAnchor").href;
```

And then you can open link

```
window.location.href = link.href
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
let url = $(".div1 a").attr('href');
window.location.href = url;
```